# Create Multiple _.templateSettings in underScore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, underscore.js-templating

Is it possible to create multiple `_.templateSettings` in `underscore.js`?

Because few of my project `HTML` files follows `'<% %>,<%=%>'`

but in `JSP` it throws a compilation error.

I changed `ERB` styles to `'<@ @>,<@= @>'`, etc. but they asked me to follow separate style for `HTML` and `JSP`.

I'm Struggling to create separate `_.templateSettings`.Otherwise we should create a method that should accept both `'<% %>,<%= %>,<@ @>,<@= @>'`etc.

I'm using `backbone` along with `spring MVC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to set up separate `_.templateSettings` for each template is going to be messy and error prone. The regexes in `_.templateSettings` can be pretty much anything (as long as they have an appropriate capture group) so you can use regexes that match both `<%...%>` and `<@...@>` delimiters. Something like this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate    : /<[%@]([\s\S]+?)[%@]>/g,
    interpolate : /<[%@]=([\s\S]+?)[%@]>/g,
    escape      : /<[%@]-([\s\S]+?)[%@]>/g
};
```

should do the trick. That will let `<% ... @>` through of course but you can add the appropriate back-references to the regexes if you care about things like that.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9Mqr4/